# Is it acceptable to use lambda calculus notation elsewhere?

Tags: notation

For example, using Leibniz notation, we can write:

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$$

But this isn't so easy using Lagrange notation.
Is it then acceptable to write this?

$$\left( \lambda x. e^x\right)' = \left( \lambda x. e^x \right)$$

Comment: Whether or not it's acceptable, it makes it much harder to read.

Comment: I dont know what means that $\left( \lambda x. e^x\right)' = \left( \lambda x. e^x \right)$. In any case this notation is far from common in the mathematical literature

Comment: Unless you are familiar with logic and the $\lambda$ calculus it is probably not a good idea. You could do something like $(x \mapsto e^x)'$ which is marginally more recognisable. Plus, the differentiation tick ' does not appear in the $\lambda$ calculus, so you are not really in either notational camp.

Comment: Nobody does that and everyone will be puzzled and wonder what you mean, even people familiar with lambda-calculus.